# Proving the invalidity arguments in quantifier logic.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am studying how to prove an argument in quantifier logic is invalid. The textbook I am using by Virginia Klenk claims that you can use a Model Universe that contains a finite number of objects to substitute in to the propositional functions. The book claims: "Where n is the number of different predicate letters in an argument form, the largest domain you need to test is one with $2^n$ individuals." Can someone explain or refer me to a proof for why this is so?

Comment: The meaning of a predicate is a subset of the domain. Consider $n=2$ i.e. a domain with only **two** individuals; we have $2^n=2^2$ subsets of the domain. Thus, we have $2^{2^n}$ possible interpretations, i.e. assignments of subsets of the domain to the two predicates.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, could you elaborate your answer some more, I am still not understanding it.